# How to style individual passages with CSS in Twine? (Sugarcube)

Tags: css, twine-game-engine, sugarcube

I'm currently doing a project in Twine and am using the Sugarcube format. I can't figure out how to style individual passages using CSS. I've tried creating classes in CSS and then tagging a passage with that class's name, but it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SugarCube documentation](http://www.motoslave.net/sugarcube/2/docs/css.html#tagged-stylesheet-warning) lists a number of ways to style a passage based on passage tags.  So, if you tagged a passage with "forest" these examples are given:

```
→ Using class selectors on <body>
body.forest { background-image: url(forest-bg.jpg); }
body.forest .passage { color: darkgreen; }
body.forest a { color: green; }
body.forest a:hover { color: lime; }

→ Using [data-tag~="…"] attribute selectors on <body>
body[data-tag~="forest"] { background-image: url(forest-bg.jpg); }
body[data-tag~="forest"] .passage { color: darkgreen; }
body[data-tag~="forest"] a { color: green; }
body[data-tag~="forest"] a:hover { color: lime; }

→ Using [data-tag~="…"] attribute selectors on <html>
html[data-tag~="forest"] { background-image: url(forest-bg.jpg); }
html[data-tag~="forest"] .passage { color: darkgreen; }
html[data-tag~="forest"] a { color: green; }
html[data-tag~="forest"] a:hover { color: lime; }
```

Make sure you put the CSS you use in your story's Stylesheet section.